# While loop error with Netwon-Raphson Method

Tags: matlab, while-loop, numerical-methods, approximation, termination

I am trying to find use to Newton-Raphson method to find the roots. It does this by making a guess and then improving the guess after each iteration until you get one of the zeros.

Because the Newton-Raphson method quickly finds the zeros, it gives me a small error immediately and after two or three iterations max it should fail to meet the conditions of the while loop. However, the problem is that when I remove the semi-colon after "error" in my loop, I start getting fractions that should break the while loop, but its like Matlab doesn't know that `123/8328423` is less than `1`. It continues to run until I manually force the program to stop running.

How do I fix this? I tried format long, format longe, and using double both in the command window, in the scrip file, and somewhere in the loop.

**Thank you in advance for any tips, suggestions, or advice that may help!!**

```
A = [1,2,-4;2,-2,-2;-4,-2,1;];
format longe
% syms x y z  
% P = x^4 + 3*x^2*y^2-z^3+y+1;
% feval(symengine,'degree',P,x)

syms x

B = mateigenvalue(A);
f(x) = simplify(matdet(B));

x0 = 1;
error = 10;
while(error > .01)
    x1 = x0 - f(x0)/(27*(x0)-3*(x0)^2);
    error = abs(((f(x0)-f(x1))/f(x0))*100)
    x0 = x1;  
end

x0 = double(x0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon the main problem is with `error`.
It starts as `double` but inside the while-loop it turns into a symbolic variable and you can't easily compare symbolic variables with scalar values (the `.01` in the while-loop condition).

Check in your workspace if `error` is symbolic (or type `class(error)` and check if `sym` is returned). I guess it is symbolic because a fraction is returned (123/8328423), as instead Matlab treats double values with decimals, not fractions.
If so, try doing (inside the while-loop) a conversion for `error` that is, under the line

```
error = abs(((f(x0)-f(x1))/f(x0))*100);
```

try putting

```
error=double(error);
```

So `error` will be temporarily converted in `double` and you can easily compare its value with `.01` to check the while-loop condition.

Also, it is bad practice to call a variable `error` since `error()` is a built-in function in Matlab. By naming a variable `error` you cannot use the `error()` function. Same story goes for other built-in functions.